# Free/OpenSource .NET Diff generator?

Tags: .net, diff, filecompare

I'm looking for a free library that can take two strings and produce a diff much like the diff's you see on edit revisions here on SO.

I'm hoping one exists, as this is a trivial part of an app I'm working on and I'd hate to waste time reinventing the wheel.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I just released my [DiffPlex](http://diffplex.codeplex.com) project which does exactly what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an MD5 hash of both files to determine if they are identical.  The SO-style revision history would be a bit more intensive.

Check out the source code for this diff tool, which might get you going in the right direction.

http://dotnet.jku.at/applications/Diff/Src.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, i found one implementation which could give you the same functionality as SO edits. [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/GenericDifferential.aspx) I am going to use it as well and hope this helps other people too.

Comment: just tested it and it works great ! i had searched for an article on this no. of times but could never find anything useful. surprisingly i found the most useful one today !